# Phrase or word for animal freezing in response to danger

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm looking for a technical (medical or biological) term for when an animal freezes in response to a perceived danger.  This is a pretty well known phenomenon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight-or-flight_response), i.e. a deer freezing in the headlights of a car, but I'm having trouble determining if there's a more precise word/phrase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not actually "fight-or-flight" but rather *[tonic immobility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonic_immobility#Tonic_immobility)*. It is an instinctive reaction in many prey animals which is similar to "playing possum" or feigning death. It increases the chance that an animal's natural camouflage will work to hide it from a predator. It doesn't deter cars, though.

Comment: The word for an animal feigning death is [thanatosis.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=thanatosis+in+animals&oq=thanatosis+in+animals&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...5975.7504.1.7863.10.9.0.1.1.0.250.1623.0j5j4.9.0...0.0.AVWepmHikao&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b33756a7ca49b63e&biw=1600&bih=698)

Comment: @spinning_plate Smells like a “bunny in the headlights” paralysis to me, no?

Comment: I don't know in what context the O.P. plans to use it, but I suspect most people would be more familiar with the term "playing dead," and perhaps unfamiliar with "tonic immobility."